# How to show messages during PIP install without --verbose argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Print statements are not shown to the user from setup.py. What method could be used to show print statements without using --verbose argument through PIP with sdists distribution?

I've tried writing to stderr.

Method One

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
logging.warning('I print to stderr by default')
```

Method Two

```
from __future__ import print_function

def myprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

myprint("Print to stderr")
```

Comment: Do you distribute your package as a wheel? In that case your post-install will be run at packaging time but not at installation time, so the message will be useless anyway.

Comment: I've tested the package. The post install script runs at install time after dependencies are installed. Assuming `pip install -e C:\absolute\path\to\package -v` is representative.

Comment: I removed references about the postscript as it detracts from the intent of the question.

Comment: Source distribution? Yes, for sdists it could work, but not for wheels.

Comment: The source distribution is sdist.

Comment: Try writing to stderr. The simplest way IMO though not the most correct.

Answer (score -1):

A very ugly workaround is to log to a log_file instead of print. Then read the output of the log file in a new window.

```
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
log = logging.getLogger()
log.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("install.log", "w"))


log.warning("\nThis is a test.\n" "Logging messages\n" "End of log\n")

def display():
    logpath = (os.getcwd() + "\install.log")
    cmd_command = ('type ' + logpath)
    print cmd_command
    os.system("start /wait cmd /k " + cmd_command)

def main():
    display()
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```